# The Monaco font doesn't work

Tags: release-loki, fonts

Installing the monaco font is successful but when I use it it changes to cousine. Using this font works on all other distro's i've tried except Elementary OS. It seems i'm not the only one with this issue.
https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/problems-with-monaco_linux-ttf-font.384/
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1477391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo sed -i '/>Monaco/{N;N;N;s/>Cousine/>Monaco/}' /etc/fonts/conf.avail/31-croscore-elementary.conf`

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! Weird that it doesn't happen automatically when installing.